# Excel Error: Repaired Records: Hyperlinks from /xl/worksheets/sheet13.xml part

Tags: excel

Our office has a macro enabled Excel Workbook located on a shared OneDrive folder. Lately, about once a week it has been giving an error message when the file is being opened:

> We found a problem with some content in **Filename Redacted** Do You
> want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source
> of this workbook, click Yes.

When I click Yes it gives the following message:

> Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the
> unreadable content. Repaired Records: Hyperlinks from
> /xl/worksheets/sheet13.xml part

The recovery log is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>error183440_01.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file ***FilePath redacted***.xlsm'</summary><repairedRecords><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Hyperlinks from /xl/worksheets/sheet13.xml part</repairedRecord></repairedRecords></recoveryLog>
```

I am not familiar with how to read the recovery log. I've been assuming that sheet13 is the sheet labeled Sheet13 in the VBA editor. That sheet, however, has no hyperlinks on the sheet. The other thought I had was that it might be referring to the 13th sheet from the left.

Could anyone point me in the right direction for how to keep this from continuing to happen? Thanks!